# pre-receive hook declined No .cqg1_configs/cip_service_pre-receive-hook.yml found

Tags: git, github

We have a private repository and when I tried pushing a new branch today I got into the below error. For making sure whether I have some configuration issues in my specific machine I have tried pushing a new branch from another machine also but ended up in the similar error.

```
pre-receive hook declined
pre_receive_hook.py: failed with exit status 1
No .cqg1_configs/cip_service_pre-receive-hook.yml found. Using default config.
Checking branch my_branch_name
ERROR:  The branch name "my_branch_name" is not allowed:
    Use one of the following instead:
    - feature/<jira id>/someName
    - release/<major number>.<minor number>.x
    - sandbox/someName
```

Does anyone have faced this issue or anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: "*tried pushing a new branch from another machine"* Pushed **where to**? To the private repository? Where it's hosted? At your own server or somewhere else?

Comment: 1. Tried pushing a new branch to the "remote/origin". 2. Yes the private repository 3. It is hosted in our own internal server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I found the problem.**

While visiting the Settings ---> Hooks tab in the GitHub page I saw that the Web hook server was showing the error message `*"Last delivery was not successful. Couldn't connect to server"*` as shown in the below image. One we fixed the server issue we were able to commit and push the branch.

[image: Web hook error]